# Graficar correlación y mostrar ecuación en ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Estoy realizando una relación potencial entre dos variables, puedo crear la gráfica y colocar la ecuación dentro pero, el problema ocurre cuando quiero cambiar la escala de los ejes a logarítmica Log10, para ello utilizo el paquete `library(sales)` y al aplicarlo la ecuación deja de mostrarse.

Aquí unos datos:

```
Datos_Grafico <- data.frame (
QLiquido <- c(31.020, 33.590, 435.500, 269.600, 477.925, 425.800, 389.100,  164.375, 104.700,  80.000,  60.320, 51.110,  39.000,  23.210,  20.390,  19.080, 135.300, 146.950, 238.960, 270.850, 350.425, 165.900,128.800)
QSolido <- c(6.936072e+01, 5.488606e+00, 2.083510e+04, 5.724525e+03, 2.229348e+04, 6.335052e+04, 2.056611e+04, 1.547919e+03, 4.322016e+02, 4.059200e+03, 1.110129e+02, 5.318507e+01, 5.265780e+01, 1.756533e+01, 7.364868e+00, 1.197842e+01, 8.994473e+02, 2.907935e+03, 4.038185e+03, 4.963760e+03, 8.983706e+03, 1.398205e+03, 1.074450e+03)
)
```

Este es el script que utilizo:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)


power_eqn = function(df, start = list(a =1,b=1)){
            m = nls(QSolido ~ a*QLiquido^b, start = start, data = df);
            eq <- substitute(italic(y) == a  ~italic(x)^b, 
           list(a = format(coef(m)[1], digits = 2), 
                b = format(coef(m)[2], digits = 2)))
            as.character(as.expression(eq))                 
}

RPotencial <- ggplot(Datos_Grafico,aes(x=QLiquido,y=QSolido)) +
      geom_point() + 
      stat_smooth(method = 'nls', formula = 'y~a*x^b', se=FALSE) +
      scale_y_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
                    labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x)))+
      scale_x_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
                    labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x)))+
      geom_text(x = 100, y = 10000, label = power_eqn(Datos_Grafico), parse = TRUE)
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dentro de tu `geom_text()` tienes a `x` y `y` fuera de `aes`. Si lo intentas de la siguiente forma te va a funcionar como lo esperabas:

```
geom_text(aes(x = 100, y = 10000, label = power_eqn(Datos_Grafico)), parse = TRUE)
```

En el total de tu ejemplo se el codigo se ve asi:

```
RPotencial <- ggplot(Datos_Grafico,aes(x=QLiquido,y=QSolido)) +
  geom_point() + 
  stat_smooth(method = 'nls', formula = 'y~a*x^b', se=FALSE) +
  scale_y_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
               labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x)))+
  scale_x_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
                labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x)))+
  geom_text(aes(x = 100, y = 10000, label = power_eqn(Datos_Grafico)), parse = TRUE
```

`aes` contiene el "mapa estético" que describe como variables en los datos son atribuidos a componentes (estéticos) de los diferentes `geom_` que usas en la definición de la figura. Al no ponerlos dentro de `aes()` ggplot2 no reconoció tus coordenadas por lo que eran.